# Using Packages to install and run homebrew

Tags: install, bash, homebrew, package-management

Using [Packages](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html) to create an installer. The app depends on a package from brew. I added a `install.sh` to the pre-installation scripts section that has this:

```
#!/bin/bash

/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"

brew install <package1>
brew install <package2>
```

But I'm getting a failure in the installer (not the build for the installer).

[image: Preview of error message]

What would be the steps for debugging this, or installing and running brew via Packages in general?

I also tried attempting to run it via simulating CI:

```
CI=1 /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

This time, it took longer before it errors out but still failed by the end.

Splitting up with preinstall being this script: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54820146/7132647

And postinstall is just the `brew install ...` commands failed as well.

Comment: I would never use homebrew, so couldn't say for sure, but I imagine it might not work correctly if it doesn't have a tty,

Comment: @MarcWilson Issue is one of the packages is only installable from homebrew, so I don't have any alternative. With TTY, there was the solution of piping it to dev/null but that didn't work out either. So HomeBrew doesn't work in general here?

Comment: As I said, I'd never use it in the first place, so I can't tell you whether Homebrew's installer cares or not.  Unless this Packager tool runs your proposed script as a priv user, installing Homebrew is going to fail anyway since it needs privs in order to screw up /usr/local to suit itself.  Re no alternative... of course you have alternatives, including building the two binaries yourself and including them yourself.  Forcing the installation of an entire packaging system seems to be a very bad idea.